# Listview y otros elementos se pierden en algunas versiones

Tags: android, json, android-listview

Tengo un tab activity con un listview, que hace una consulta json. Cuando lo pruebo en el emulador todo funciona bien, sin embargo en algunos dispositivos el listview no se visualiza, que puede estar sucediendo?

Este es mi Res/Layout/movimientos

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabcontainer"
    android:theme="@style/TabWidgetTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF812899" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <include
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/IngresosLayout"
                    layout="@layout/listado_de_ingresos"/>

            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <include
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/PagosLayout"
                    layout="@layout/listado_de_egresos">

                </include>

            </LinearLayout>



        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

```
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class Movimientos extends Fragment {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> IngresoList, EgresoList;
private ListView lv, li;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movimientos, container, false);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hideFloatingActionButton();

    //Resources res = getResources();
    IngresoList = new ArrayList<>();
    EgresoList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listaegresos);
    li = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listaingresos);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    final TabHost tabs = (TabHost)view.findViewById(R.id.tabcontainer);
    tabs.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.IngresosLayout);
    spec.setIndicator("e-Pay Enviados");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tabs.newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.PagosLayout);
    spec2.setIndicator("e-Pay Recibidos");
    tabs.addTab(spec2);



    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);



    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabs.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9533AF")); // selected

    tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {


            for (int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF812899")); // unselected
                TextView tv = (TextView) tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            }
            tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabs.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9533AF")); // selected
            TextView tv = (TextView) tabs.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff00"));

        }
    });



    getDataMovEntrada();
    getDataMovSalida();

    return view;
}

private void getDataMovSalida() {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setTitle("Estamos procesando la transacción");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Aguarda un momento");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.show();

    final String Usercorreo = Constantes.CORREO;

    MovRequest movRequest = new MovRequest(Usercorreo,  new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("Pago Response", response);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            //JSONObject jsonObject=null;
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray movimientos = jsonObject.getJSONArray("movimientos");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i=0; i < movimientos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = movimientos.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id=c.getString("idTrans");
                    String comercioName=c.getString("P.NOMBRE");
                    String comercioRif=c.getString("P.RIF");
                    String comercioLogo=c.getString("IMGPERFIL");
                    String fmonto=c.getString("monto");
                    String monto = fmonto +" +" ;
                    String fecha=c.getString("fecha");
                    String concepto=c.getString("concepto");
                    String Norecibo ="No. de control: " + id;

                    HashMap<String, String> egresos = new HashMap<>();

                    egresos.put("id", Norecibo);
                    egresos.put("comercio", comercioName);
                    egresos.put("rif", comercioRif);
                    egresos.put(Constantes.TRANSACCION_COMERCIO_LOGO, comercioLogo);
                    egresos.put("monto", monto);
                    egresos.put("fecha", fecha);
                    egresos.put("concepto", concepto);


                    EgresoList.add(egresos);
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Estoy aqui", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                ListAdapter adapter =
                        new MyMovAdapter(
                                getActivity(),
                                EgresoList,
                                R.layout.lista_egresos,
                                new String[]{"comercio", "rif","monto", "fecha", "concepto", "id"},
                                new int[]{R.id.txtCOMERCIOnombre,
                                        R.id.txtCOMERCIOrif, R.id.txtMOVmonto, R.id.txtMOVfecha, R.id.txtMOVconcepto,  R.id.txtMOVid});
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    });
    requestQueue.add(movRequest);
}

private void getDataMovEntrada() {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setTitle("Estamos procesando la transacción");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Aguarda un momento");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.show();

    final String Usercorreo = Constantes.CORREO;

    MovxRequest movxRequest = new MovxRequest(Usercorreo,  new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("Pago Response", response);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            //JSONObject jsonObject=null;
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray xmovimientos = jsonObject.getJSONArray("movimientos");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i=0; i < xmovimientos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject xc = xmovimientos.getJSONObject(i);
                    String xid=xc.getString("idTrans");
                    String xcomercioName=xc.getString("P.NOMBRE");
                    String xcomercioRif=xc.getString("P.RIF");
                    String xcomercioLogo=xc.getString("IMGPERFIL");
                    String xfmonto=xc.getString("monto");
                    String xmonto = xfmonto +" -" ;
                    String xfecha=xc.getString("fecha");
                    String xconcepto=xc.getString("concepto");
                    String xNorecibo ="No. de control: " + xid;

                    HashMap<String, String> ingresos = new HashMap<>();

                    ingresos.put("xid", xNorecibo);
                    ingresos.put("xcomercio", xcomercioName);
                    ingresos.put("xrif", xcomercioRif);
                    ingresos.put(Constantes.TRANSACCION_COMERCIO_LOGOX, xcomercioLogo);
                    ingresos.put("xmonto", xmonto);
                    ingresos.put("xfecha", xfecha);
                    ingresos.put("xconcepto", xconcepto);


                    IngresoList.add(ingresos);
                }

                ListAdapter adapter =
                        new MyMovxAdapter(
                                getActivity(),
                                IngresoList,
                                R.layout.lista_exgresos,
                                new String[]{"xcomercio", "xrif","xmonto", "xfecha", "xconcepto", "xid"},
                                new int[]{R.id.txtCOMERCIOnombre,
                                        R.id.txtCOMERCIOrif, R.id.txtMOVmonto, R.id.txtMOVfecha, R.id.txtMOVconcepto,  R.id.txtMOVid});
                li.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    });
    requestQueue.add(movxRequest);
}

     }
```

Ahora bien, en dispositivos versiones >5.0.3 se visualiza bien, en 5.0.1 no, ni decir versiones anteriores por que la app se me crashea

Comment: Primero que todo deberías de dar más detalles de la duda que tienes así como imágenes de el error y el trozo de código que que estás utilizando para hacer esto, así como fórmulas tu pregunta es complicado brindar ayuda...

Comment: El asunto es que como no me arroja ningun error, no se que parte del codigo copiar. Sin embargo actualizare con el codigo de toda la actividad:

Comment: Que version de android tiene el dipositivo que no te funciona?

Comment: El dispositivo tiene version 5.0.1, le aparece la pantalla en blanco